# Webpack 2 Missing module

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to require BigVideo.js from "components" folder as video.js too. Jquery and videojs are required by BigVideo.js script and when I try to webpack it, this is what I get

"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'videojs' in '/Users/Sempa/Desktop/PersonalWeb/app/components/BigVideo/lib'"

Here is my screenshot of webpack configuration and main.js file. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Please help.

[image]